# Portia interface is not working

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, portia

I've a problem with running and opening the portia interface on my mac,
I installed portia like it's written on the doc:
git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia

and then these two vagrant two command:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32

vagrant up
```

The Virtual box is running,
but when I try to open the interface through: localhost:8000 , nothing opens!

Could any body help guys?

Comment: Why are you using `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32`? Just `git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia` and `vagrant up`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contributor of Portia here, sorry about that, the Vagrant build has been broken for a while. It's fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/pull/330) that we haven't merged yet but will do soon. You can use Portia with Vagrant by cloning the pull request.

```
vagrant destroy
git fetch origin pull/330/head:pr-330
git checkout pr-330
vagrant up
```

Comment: I had the same result dude, I ran the 4 commands, and tried to access localhost on port 9001 or 8000, but I got nothing :S 

Do I miss something?

Comment: Not sure, seems like maybe vagrant isn't setting up ports correctly. Can you access the VM with vagrant ssh?